# Avoid TSwitch's OnSwitch Event in Firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

When setting TSwitch's IsChecked property programatically, the event OnSwitch getting called. How to avoid this? I would like the OnSwitch event to be called only in case of user interaction, when the user switch the control by clicking.

Comment: Maybe (I can't test now) you can use `OnClick` to detect user actions instead of `OnSwitch`. `OnClick`should nt occur if you change state programmatically.

Comment: The problem is that In OnClick event i dont get the proper/new state of the switch. For example if the switch been set to off and i change it to on, i get the previous off state (OnChecked = false).

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear. Another possibility, which I know works, is to nil `OnSwitch` before programmatically changing state and reset `OnSwitch` right after.

Comment: It is not just Firemonkey, or this control it can happen in VCL too. Delphi doesn't seem terribly consistent in this regard. Under some circumstances and with complex inter-related controls it can result in a fatal embrace sometimes. Tom Brunberg's solution seems a good one. I have used class variables in the past but that it relatively cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `OnSwitch = Switch1Switch()` and the following button `OnClick` just simulating the programmatic change, you can do the following:

```
procedure TForm29.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Switch1.OnSwitch := nil;
  Switch1.IsChecked := not Switch1.IsChecked;
  Switch1.OnSwitch := Switch1Switch;
end;
```

This changes the state of the switch and fires `OnSwitch` when user flips the switch, but not when state is changed programmatically.

Comment: A more common and generic solution is to save the previous `OnSwitch` handler to a local variable, and then assign the variable back to the event: `var OldHandler: TNotifyEvent; begin OldHandler := Switch1.OnSwitch; Switch1.OnSwitch := nil; try Switch1.IsChecked := not Switch1.IsChecked; finally Switch1.OnSwitch := OldHandler; end; end;` If you have multiple controls to disable, this code can be easily wrapped in a reusable function that you can pass the desired object to as an input parameter.